# How to execute an external program as part of an SQL query?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am trying to figure out how to embed a call to an external program in a SQL query. The idea is that as the SQL query executes, it would be able to call an external program, passing along records from a database, and receiving output that could then be used by that SQL query.

The reason that I want to do this, and that I cannot consider alternative approaches, is that I have been tasked with manually re-creating some database benchmarks in Python using SQLite and the SQLAlchemy library (specifically these benchmarks: https://amplab.cs.berkeley.edu/benchmark/).

One of the SQL queries described there (Query 4) begins with the following SQL statement:

```
CREATE TABLE url_counts_partial AS 
  SELECT TRANSFORM (line)
    USING "python /root/url_count.py" as (sourcePage, destPage, cnt) 
  FROM documents;
```

Here is their description of Query 4:

> This query calls an external Python function which extracts and aggregates URL information from a web crawl dataset. It then aggregates a total count per URL.

The table "documents" contains a single column called "line" which represents individual lines of HTML. The "url_count.py" program simply parses lines from sys.stdin and prints lines of tab-separated information (you can see url_count.py here: https://github.com/amplab/benchmark/blob/master/runner/udf/url_count.py).

I attempted to run the following:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///myDatabase.db')

result = engine.execute("""SELECT TRANSFORM (line) 
             USING 'python /root/url_count.py' as (sourcePage, destPage, cnt)
             FROM documents"""")
```

Every time I try running this, however, I get an exception with a complaint at the bottom about a syntax error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) near "USING": syntax error
```

I have tried tweaking the syntax in every way I can think of. I have tried moving url_count.py to the local directory. I have tried executing the full statement instead (i.e. adding back in "CREATE TABLE url_counts_partial AS"). I have tried running simplified versions of it against toy databases. I have also tried replacing the call to a python program with calls to simple bash commands. Nothing seems to work. Nor can I seem to find any online documentation for the keywords TRANSFORM or USING.

Am I just making a silly error somewhere? Or if not, is there an easier/more correct way to execute this command (while still staying faithful to the original query)? Failing that, even just knowing where to find the man pages for TRANSFORM or USING would be very helpful. I have not had any problems with any of their other queries, so I don't know why this one should turn out to be such a headache.

Comment: Do you need to escape your single quotes? And why are you trying to run a program from SQL? That usually points to improper design somewhere.

Comment: A good idea, but I tried escaping single quotes, and it did not help. I also tried double quotes, both escaped and un-escaped, to no avail. If I understand correctly, neither should require escaping between triple quotes in python, but just to be sure, I did try every permutation.

Comment: In response to why I am trying to run a program from SQL: since my task is to faithfully re-create existing benchmarks, I have to follow their design. For better or worse, that is the design that they went with, so I need to follow suit for the sake of fidelity to the original benchmarks. You can read more about the benchmarks I'm reproducing here:  https://amplab.cs.berkeley.edu/benchmark/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite has no such USING clause to call an external program.

The nearest mechanism would be a [table-valued function](http://www.sqlite.org/vtab.html#tabfunc2), but this is not exposed by the Python `sqlite3` module.

The easiest way to do this would be execute that program manually, and convert its output into INSERT commands.